# Lambda Copy Image from one bucket to another after resize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am receiving images on a S3 bucket.  Using a lambda function, I want to resize the images to a thumbnail and copy the thumbnail into another s3 bucket.  The following is the code:

```
import json
import boto3
import ast
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from PIL import Image

s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
s3_res = boto3.resource('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    tnlBuck = s3_res.Bucket('aivuthumbnail')
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket=record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        ikey = record['s3']['object']['key']
        params = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': ikey}
        proj = ikey.split('_')[0]
        outlet = ikey.split('_')[1]
        parameter = ikey.split('_')[2]
        dat = ikey.split('_')[3]
        table = client.Table("telescopeImageReceipt")
        table.put_item(Item={'image':ikey,'project':proj,'outlet':outlet,'parameter':parameter,'date':dat})
        url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object', Params=params)
        with urlopen(url) as conn:
            image = Image.open(conn)
            MAX_SIZE = (100, 100) 
            image.thumbnail(MAX_SIZE)
            image.copy("Bucket":tnlBuck)
```

I have changed the last line to various combinations.  But nothing works.  The lambda function has full access to S3, Dynamodb and Cloudwatch logs.

The following were some of the options I tried and got the error messages:

```
Option Tried:  tnlBuck.copy(image, ikey)
Error : Expecting dictionary formatted: {"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": key} but got <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image

Option Tried: s3_client.copy({"Bucket":tnlBuck, "Key":ikey})
Error:  TypeError: copy() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Bucket' and ‘Key'

Option tried:  image.copy({"Bucket":tnlBuck, "Key":ikey})
Error:  TypeError: copy() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Other options had more or less similar errors or thrown a `syntax error`.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: added the error messages

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/jangia/87606ee41665b2a061869a728ea19ca4 if it doesn't help you can contact me on twitter and I can help you.

Comment: @JanGiacomelli Thanks a ton...the code worked perfectly.  I have made a couple of changes 1. added `import io` library and 2. passed on the first index of 0 into `img_bytes.seek()` .  thank you again.   I can accept the answer.

Comment: Great. Will write an answer later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an S3 bucket to copy the image to it and not the *PIL Image* object.
Your code should be changed to this:

```
import json
import io
import boto3
import ast
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from PIL import Image

s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
s3_res = boto3.resource('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    tnlBuck = s3_res.Bucket('aivuthumbnail')
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket=record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        ikey = record['s3']['object']['key']
        params = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': ikey}
        proj = ikey.split('_')[0]
        outlet = ikey.split('_')[1]
        parameter = ikey.split('_')[2]
        dat = ikey.split('_')[3]
        table = client.Table("telescopeImageReceipt")
        table.put_item(Item={'image':ikey,'project':proj,'outlet':outlet,'parameter':parameter,'date':dat})
        url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object', Params=params)
        with urlopen(url) as conn:
            image = Image.open(conn)
            MAX_SIZE = (100, 100) 
            image.thumbnail(MAX_SIZE)
            img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
            image.save(img_bytes, format='JPEG')
            img_bytes.seek(0)
            tnl_bucket.Object(ikey).put(Body=img_bytes.read())
```

You should use *tnl_bucket* to create a new object from thumbnailed image bytes.

```
img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
image.save(img_bytes, format='JPEG')
img_bytes.seek(0)
tnl_bucket.Object(ikey).put(Body=img_bytes.read())
```

PIL can save to file on path or BytesIO. You need to return to the stream beginning with *.seek(0)* so it can be read from the start to get bytes for *put* method.